# Show more info in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, state, show-hide

I want to show more info onclick, but I have different divs to show/hide . 
So. I do it this way : 
The state is :

```
this.state = {
        showMore: false,
        showRewards: false,
        fees: false,
        showFees: false
    };
```

One of the divs:

> ```
>                       <div className='some'>
>                           <h3 >Rewards <i className="icon-im-rewards"></i></h3>
>                                   <h5 className="showMoreDetails" onClick={ () => this.show('rewards') }>{ showRewards ? '-' : '+' } { showRewards ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More' }</h5>
>                           {   showRewards && detail.rewards.reward.map((name, i) =>
>                                   <p key={i}> { name }</p>
>                               )
>                           }
>                       </div>
> ```

The function :

show (name) {
    let { showMore, showRewards, showFees } = this.state;

```
if (name === 'hightlights' && showMore === false) {
    this.setState({
        showMore: true
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        showMore: false
    });
}

if (name === 'rewards' && showRewards === false) {
    this.setState({
        showRewards: true
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        showRewards: false
    });
}

if (name === 'fees' && showFees === false) {
    this.setState({
        showFees: true
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        showFees: false
    });
}
```

This is too long, ugly and doesn't work correct (I can only see one expanded div at a time) How to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a better and a cleaner way:

```
function show (name) { 

  let { showMore, showRewards, showFees } = this.state;
  showMore = name === 'hightlights' && showMore === false;
  showRewards = name === 'rewards' && showRewards === false;
  showFees = name === 'fees' && showFees === false;

  this.setState({
    showFees,
    showRewards, 
    showMore
  });
```

Comment: it's much better, but I still only can see one at a time

Answer (score 0):

It could be easier if you could show us the structure of detail & rewards. I guess you are mapping a single element here that's why it is printing single element. However, try changing this line,

```
detail.rewards.reward.map((name, i) => <p key={i}> { name }</p> )
```

replace with below code:

```
detail.rewards.map((reward, i) => <p key={i}> { reward.name }</p> )
```